# Need to join a lambda function (python) to CloudFormation template in YAML, How can i achieve this?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm stuck trying to embed the lambda into this CF template. Lambda is coded on python and CF in YAML, im having a hard time converting the lambda to Yaml.

A little bit of help here would be appreciated. I need to add the lambda to the CF template. Any explanation will be also useful.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: CH CloudFormation template for Deploy and Init of DynamoDB Table
Parameters:
  dbTableName:
    Type: String
    Default: ClientOrders
    Description: Enter the name used for DynamoDB Table
  phoneNumber:
    Type: String
    Default: 1115551111
    Description: Enter your phone number

Resources:
  OrdersTable:
    Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
    Properties:
      TableName: !Ref dbTableName # !Join [ "-", [ !Ref "AWS::StackName", !Ref dbTableName ] ]
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: PhoneNumber
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: OrderNumber
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: PhoneNumber
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: OrderNumber
          KeyType: RANGE
      TimeToLiveSpecification:
        AttributeName: ExpirationTime
        Enabled: true
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: '10'
        WriteCapacityUnits: '5'
    DependsOn:
      - DynamoDBQueryPolicy
  DynamoDBQueryPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
    Properties:
      PolicyName: DynamoDBQueryPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 'dynamodb:*'
            Resource: '*'
      Roles:
        - !Ref OrdersTableQueryRole
  OrdersTableQueryRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - dynamodb.amazonaws.com
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /

  phoneRecord:
    DependsOn:
      - OrdersTable
    Type: 'Custom::CrtUpdDltDynamodbDocumentLambda'
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt dynamoSetupLambda.Arn
      DynamoTableName: !Ref dbTableName # !Join [ "-", [ !Ref "AWS::StackName", !Ref dbTableName ] ]
      # DynamoKeyProperty: PhoneNumber
      DynamoItem: !Sub |
        [{
          "PhoneNumber": "784578745",
          "OrderNumber": "11547854",
          "someKey": "someValue"
        },
        {
          "PhoneNumber": "${phoneNumber}",
          "OrderNumber": "11545154",
          "someKey": "someValue"
        }]
  dynamoSetupLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: custom resource function invoked for intitial configuration of dynamodb
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Timeout: 300
      MemorySize: 128
      Role: !GetAtt 'OrdersTableQueryRole.Arn'
      Runtime: python3.8
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import json, boto3, os, threading, logging
          import cfnresponse
          def setup_stack(tableName, dynamoItems):
              dynamodb_client = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name=os.environ['AWS_REGION'])
              try:
                  dynamodb_client_table = dynamodb_client.Table(tableName)
                  with dynamodb_client_table.batch_writer() as batch:
                      for message in dynamoItems:
                          batch.put_item(
                              Item=message
                          )
              except Exception as exc:
                  print(exc)
          # def remove_stack(tableName): # will need to clear maybe?
          #     dynamodb_client = boto3.resource(tableName, region_name=os.environ['AWS_REGION'])
          #     dynamodb_client_table = dynamodb_client.Table(table_name)
          #     continue
          def timeout(event, context):
              logging.error('Execution is about to time out, sending failure response to CloudFormation')
              cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.FAILED, {}, None)
          def lambda_handler(event, context):
              print('Received event: %s' % json.dumps(event))
              # make sure we send a failure to CloudFormation if the function is going to timeout
              timer = threading.Timer((context.get_remaining_time_in_millis()
                      / 1000.00) - 0.5, timeout, args=[event, context])
              timer.start()
              
              status = cfnresponse.SUCCESS
              try:
                  dynamoItems = event['ResourceProperties']['DynamoItem']
                  dynamoTable = event['ResourceProperties']['DynamoTableName']
                  if event['RequestType'] == 'Delete':
                      print("Not going to remvove yet")
                      # remove_stack(dynamoTable)
                  else:
                      setup_stack(dynamoTable, json.loads(dynamoItems))
              except Exception as e:
                  logging.error('Exception: %s' % e, exc_info=True)
                  status = cfnresponse.FAILED
              finally:
                  timer.cancel()
                  cfnresponse.send(event, context, status, {}, None)
```

Lambda:

```
    from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
import json
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print(event)
    PhoneNumber=event['Details']['ContactData']['Attributes'].get('PhoneNumber',"Not Available")
    table = dynamodb.Table('ClientOrders')
    try:
      response = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('PhoneNumber').eq(PhoneNumber)
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
        return {
                "Success":"False",
                "Reason":e.response['Error']['Message']
               }
    else:
        #item = response['Item']
        print("GetItem succeeded:")
        print(json.dumps(response))
        print(response['Items'])
        if "Items" in response:
            return{
                "Success":"True",
                "PhoneNumber":response["Items"][0]["PhoneNumber"]
                }
        else:
            return {
                "Success":"False",
                "Reason":"No Records Found"
            }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At first glance this looks good, can you share the error message you're getting?

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong? Why it does not work? What is expected outcome? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, you need to use ZipFile and mantain the format from the CF template. I was checking if was valid through the CF designer builder but i would suggest to try to run it anyway and in case of errors analyze it.